# Security Kendo UI for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have just started using angular with Kendo UI, I would like to ask you if the security specified on the manual(https://angular.io/guide/security) also applies to the Kendo components or if for security (XSS for example) more should be done.

Thanks.

Comment: this feels like a question you should ask them.